# How to read audio file from google cloud storage bucket and play with ipd in a datalab notebook

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datalab, librosa

I want to play a sound file in a datalab notebook which I read from a google cloud storage bucket.  How to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import IPython.display as ipd
import librosa
import soundfile as sf
import io
from google.cloud import storage

BUCKET = 'some-bucket'

# Create a Cloud Storage client.
gcs = storage.Client()

# Get the bucket that the file will be uploaded to.
bucket = gcs.get_bucket(BUCKET)

# specify a filename
file_name = 'some_dir/some_audio.wav'

# read a blob
blob = bucket.blob(file_name)
file_as_string = blob.download_as_string()

# convert the string to bytes and then finally to audio samples as floats 
# and the audio sample rate
data, sample_rate = sf.read(io.BytesIO(file_as_string))

left_channel = data[:,0]  # I assume the left channel is column zero

# enable play button in datalab notebook
ipd.Audio(left_channel, rate=sample_rate)
```

Comment: Would you mind accepting your own answer? For future reference of the community, of course. I think that you have to wait 2 days to accept your own answer, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You are correct.  I need to wait 2 days before I accept my own answer.  It took me quite a while to do this, so I figured it would be good to post a solution in case someone had the same question.